# TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I've just been doing some random stuff in Python 3.5.
And with 15 minutes of spare time, I came up with this:

```
a = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w",
 "x", "y", "z"}
len_a = len(a)
list = list(range(0, len_a))
message = ""
wordlist = [ch for ch in message]
len_wl = len(wordlist)
for x in list:
    print (a[x])
```

But that satisfying feel of random success did not run over me.
Instead, the feeling of failure did:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/spathen/PycharmProjects/soapy/soup.py", line 9, in  <module>
print (a[x])
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
```

Please help

Comment: Side-note: Don't name a variable `list`; from the moment you assign it, you've name-shadowed the `list` constructor. For that matter, you may as well just loop over your values directly (`for x in a: print(x)`); iterating indices and indexing is distinctly non-pythonic, not to mention slower and less self-documenting.

Comment: Better to define `a` via: `import string` / `a = string.ascii_lowercase`

Answer (score 11):

Try square brackets:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w",
 "x", "y", "z"]
```

i.e.: use an `list` instead of a `set`

Comment: thanks man, you saved me searching in my code at least 15 minutes.

Answer (score 6):

As the error message says, `set` indeed does not support indexing, and `a` is a `set`, since you used set literals (braces) to specify its elements (available since Python 3.1). However, to extract elements from a set, you can simply iterate over them:

```
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

@Sakib, your set `a` is already iterable.  Please consider using this updated code instead of accessing elements by index.

```
a = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}
for x in a:
  print ( x )
```

Additionally, your code doesn't show enough intent for us to help you get to your ultimate goal.
Examples:

1. `range()` also returns an iterable type, so there's no reason to convert it to a `list`
2. It's bad practice to re-use (overwrite) the `list` keyword, and it doing so will lead to many more problems
3. `len_wl` doesn't serve a purpose yet
4. Because of #3, neither `wordlist` nor `message` have a purpose either

Hope this helps

PS - don't forget to select an answer

Comment: nested loops make for n^m required time for performing a given task. Imagine this:
I have a set with 1000000 entries and have to loop over the whole other set to get one specific single sample. makes for 1000000 * 1000000 iterations

Answer (score -1):

try to modify your code like this.

```
a = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", 
      "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w",
      "x", "y", "z"}
list_a = list(a)
len_a = len(a)
list = list(range(0, len_a))
message = ""
wordlist = [ch for ch in message]
len_wl = len(wordlist)
for x in list:
   print list_a[x]
```

set doesn't support indexing however list support it, so here i convert set to list and get index of list.